# How can I get a user's first, last name, and attribute from keycloak with the Java API?

Tags: java, keycloak

I can get a token from keycloak given a user and password with the Java API code:

```
 AccessTokenResponse tokenresponse = authzClient.obtainAccessToken(user, password);
```

How can I get this user's firstname, lastname, as well as other attributes from Keycloak? Such as Id?

Comment: What about [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.4/javadocs/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.html#user-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: Thanks very much for the link! Are these REST calls?

Comment: I would expect so given names of these classes. At least some of these ought to be.

Comment: is there a direct way to do it without relying on REST?

Comment: What's a "direct" way? Is your user data stored locally? If it is, why rely on keycloak at all and not just query the datastore?

Comment: By "direct", I mean non-REST. I am already providing a REST service to a client. I wonder about performance issues for one about using another REST call to keycloak. And why should I use REST to access keycloak when it is local to my service? I "should" be able to access it directly through the Java API. But if I can't find an alternative, it might be a temporary solution until I can find a better solution.

Comment: But for lack of anything better at the moment I will try it.

Comment: If you have local store, and it's configured like a local store, then it's unlikely that the resource will not be local. On the other hand, if the store is not known to be local, then the call would amount to a REST call to 127.0.0.1 (after all resolutions). However, my other question is still unanswered: if you store locally, why use keycloak for this at all?

Comment: keycloak is for security. To validate, authenticate users

Comment: Exactly: to validate and authenticate. Not to serve as a user attributes store.

Answer (score 2):

The code I've used just gets the info from the `AccessToken`.  This is taken from a JAX-RS service but it isn't clear how you're trying to access it.  Perhaps it can still give you some ideas.

```
@Path("/something")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response aMethod(@Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    Principal principal = securityContext.getUserPrincipal();

    KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) principal;

    AccessToken accessToken = keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();

    // first name
    accessToken.getGivenName()
    // last name
    accessToken.getFamilyName();
    // email
    accessToken.getEmail();
    // roles
    accessToken.getRealmAccess().getRoles();
```

Comment: Which AccessToken are you using? I am using org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse and it doesn't have methods like the ones you are using and the Token itself is just a String.

Comment: But of course, your idea makes sense! I would like to do it this way if I can.

Comment: Sorry about that - I've updated the post with more info.